# Are there any sources on how common the most frequently used passwords are?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

For example, I'm trying to work what percentage of passwords are within the top 500 most common passwords.

Comment: Have you done any research? There are tons of resources about this very thing over many years,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Analysis from 2014

*From [wpengine](https://wpengine.com/unmasked/)*

This website has some really good statistics from analysing 10 million passwords. You can look at [this FAQ](https://xato.net/ten-million-passwords-faq-3b2752ed3b4c) for information on how the 10 million passwords were collected.

#### Just to select a few statistics from wpengine:

- 0.6 percent of passwords are 123456
- A hacker could guess *16 out of 1000* passwords by using the 10 most popular passwords
- 8.4 percent of passwords end with a number
- The average entropy of a password is 21.6

#### Top 10 passwords:

- 123456
- password
- 12345678
- qwerty
- 123456789
- 12345
- 1234
- 111111
- 1234567
- dragon

#### Some nice images from the analysis:

[Top 50 passwords](https://wpengine.com/unmasked/assets/images/5-most-used-passwords.png)

[Password length](https://wpengine.com/unmasked/assets/images/password-length-breakdown.png)

[Common keyboard patterns](https://wpengine.com/unmasked/assets/images/commonkeyboardpatterns.gif)

[Most used numbers](https://wpengine.com/unmasked/assets/images/most-used-numbers-passwords.png)